# modifying `wp_register` function replacing site admin with profile link

Tags: wordpress

I would like to use the `wp_register` function in my template's top bar. 

I want to keep the functionality that shows a register option to non-logged useres, but for logged in users I want to change "site admin" to "profile" and have the HTML generated by the function create the proper `a` tag contents to link to the user's profile. 
What should i change in the wp_register function? where should i place it so it doesn't get erased in the next update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about ...

```
add_filter('register','adapt_site_admin_link');

function adapt_site_admin_link($link) 
{
   global $current_user;
   get_currentuserinfo();
   $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
   $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

   if($user_role == 'administrator')     $link = str_replace('Site Admin','Site Admin',$link);
   elseif($user_role == 'editor')        $link = str_replace('Site Admin','Editor Admin',$link);
   elseif($user_role == 'author')        $link = str_replace('Site Admin','Author Admin',$link);
   elseif($user_role == 'contributor')   $link = str_replace('Site Admin','Contributor Admin',$link);
   elseif($user_role == 'subscriber')    $link = str_replace('Site Admin','Profile',$link);

   return $link;
}
```

first result in google for: wp_register function change Site Admin

Source: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/changing-site-admin-link